# object oriented programming => Change the Object in runtime

Tags: vb.net

is it possible to write Object Oriented code where an object can be overwritten?

example I want to achieve:
In a program you can enter the fileserver from 2 sides, inside a company (Explorer in Windows) or outside a company (sFTP).

Is it possible to switch the object "FileAccess" depending on where you have access to?

It would be amazing if you could change it during runtime without always having to write "if on the inside then do WindowsExplorerThingy, else do FTP thingy"

but instead: FileSaver.DoWork would straight go to FTP OR WindowsExplorer and do the work there. I would have to write 2 different objects (one for WindowsExplorer and one for FTP).
Both Objects would have the same "functionality" like openfile or deletefile, ...

Sorry for the dumb question. I am still writing functional in 2018 and trying to make the switch to Object Oriented Programming.

Comment: new user => read [ask] and take the [TOUR]

Comment: commenters => take you through how this FAQ works

Comment: An object can have mutable state (this is, usually, the case). But you cannot (usually) replace it with another object. (A reference to an object can also be changed to reference a different object, but that doesn't replace the original object.)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you need a FileAccess object that has the a set of members (methods, properties, etc.) but where those members work differently depending on whether this is an internal access or an external access.

There are two ways of doing this:

1. Inherit from a common base class.
2. Implement an interface.

**Inheritance**

To use this method, create a base class called FileAcccess that contains all the 
members that you need. Then create classes FileAccessInternal and FileAccessExternal that inherit from FileAccess. The derived classes can override members from FileAccess that need to work differently. Now you can create an object of the appropriate derived class (depending on the type of access) and pass it to a method that expects a FileAccess object. The FileAccess object will use the appropriate methods from the derived classes.

For more information about inheritance, read [Inheritance Basics (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/inheritance-basics).

**Interface**

An interface defines a set of methods. The interface provides no code for these methods, it simply provides the signature of each method (method name, argument list and return type). A class that implements the interface promises to include each of the interface's methods.

To use this method, create an Interface called IFileAccess (the initial "I" is not required, but is customary for an interface) that lists all the methods you need. Then create classes FileAccessInternal and FileAccessExternal that implement the IFileAccess interface. The classes that implement the interface must provide the code for each of the method. Now you can create an object of the appropriate derived class (depending on the type of access) and pass it to a method that expects an IFileAccess object. The IFileAccess object will use the appropriate methods from the implementing classes.

For more information about interfaces, read [Interfaces (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/interfaces/).